# How to search in Laravel Datatables results greater than a number and not by exact matches?

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have a Laravel project where I use DataTables to list some results from the database. Every result has `width` and `height` stored in the database. How to perform a search query where I am not looking for exact results, but for results that are greater than the added number?

For example if I search a `width` of `100` then I want to get all results that are greater than `100` -> `101`, `102` etc.

This is my controller:

```
public function datatable()
{
   $data = Unit::with('type')->get();

   $datatable = DataTables::of($data)
       ->editColumn('type', function($model){
           return $model->type->name;
       })
       ->make();

   return $datatable;
}
```

And this is the JS:

```
var datatableColumns = [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'width', width: '1%' },
            { data: 'height', width: '1%' },
            { data: 'type', width: '1%' },
        ];

$('#datatable').dataTable({
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   ajax: $('#datatable').data('src'),
   columns: datatableColumns,
});
```

At the moment if I search for `100` I am only getting results that has a `width` of `100`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deal with this...
This is how I would do it.  On your page with the datatables create a post form for things you are searching for.  Use ajax post to your controller data endpoint. From here you can work the logic of your searches. So in this case it's just a matter of seeing the request that is 100 and you can build your eloquent statement per the request from the front.
So your eloquent would be something like this...

```
$data = Unit::where('width', '<', $request->width)->with('type')->get();
```

Obviously you can do some data shaping before it gets to you eloquent statement and just use a variable from logic before you do the query.